# Nested types/classes in Angular within constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript, class, nested

I'm quite new to nested datastructure typing and I looked at many answers but this left me even more confused so right now I'm not even sure if I use the right terms to ask (sorry for that). What I want to achieve is to make an existing angular project more type- or class-'secure'. When I work with data I try to keep the structure simple like:

```
export class Filter {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public description: string) {
    }
}
```

so I use it like:

```
filterSelected: Filter;
```

Now, I want to add some class/typedefinition to data I get from the API (e.g. when I run a service). For the moment I'm using **any** for nested structure. So my call looks like:

```
this.httpc.get<any>(url, { params }).subscribe(...
```

which is a working but not a very nice solution. I'm wondering how the class for the API response is built when it looks like:

```
[
  {
    "heading": "string",
    "employee": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    },
    "manager": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    },
    "branches": [
      {
        "postcode": 0,
        "city": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Do I have to use an interface instead of a class? And how to construct it with nested items?

Comment: You're going to want to create a interface for your api response, but you can return a class like `.pipe(map(res => new Filter(res)))`. The constructor of the `Filter` class would then take an object that represents your api response

Comment: Thanks! That leeds me to the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an interface for the above API response like below and then use this type for your Http response which will then look like this

```
this.httpc.get<APIResponse[]>(url, { params }).subscribe(...

export interface APIResponse {
  heading: string;
  employee: Employee;
  manager: Employee;
  branches: Branch[];
}

interface Branch {
  postcode: number;
  city: string;
}

interface Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```